# Error in retaining an invalid value for date fields in form

Tags: spring, validation, datetime, date, spring-mvc

I am relatively new to the Spring framework and am facing a problem that I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I have a form with two date fields, date 1 and date 2. If date 1 field is an invalid date and the date 2 is a valid date, when validations are performed, the date 1 field's invalid value is not displayed. Instead the  date 2 value is populated in the date 1 field box.

Could someone please tell me why and where I am going wrong.

I believe this is a framework error with the way I have configured spring and not a problem with my code. I tried debugging through my code and it works as it is supposed to.

Comment: Could you please post server side validation code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It looks like you are using a customDateEditor that is different from the one that Spring provides. Check if you are importing

```
   org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor
```

in your customPropertyEditorRegistrar class... It will probably help.

Comment: Had just figured it out a short while ago.. but thanks for your help.